# How to serialize multi-types Collection with IXmlSerializable

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm writing an xml  that seem decent to me but i have issue reading into last collection.

Xml

```
  <SWorkspace Title="Default" NosWorkSpaceGuid="69c4d731-a44d-4eaf-b61c-12042bfaf714">
<ChartWindow WindowsGuid="93213993-7215-4006-9e05-e30dff98b038" Top="0" Left="NaN" Height="0" Width="NaN">
<ArrayOfBaseContener xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<BaseContener ContenerGuid="393bc0e5-bce0-4446-becd-a8796f18ccb9">
<ArrayOfBaseIndicator>
<BaseIndicator Name="Ohlc" BarType="unknow" type="NosIndicator.Ohlc.Ohlc, NosIndicators, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
<ArrayOfBaseRenderableSeriesViewModel>
<BaseRenderableSeriesViewModel xsi:type="CandlestickRenderableSeriesViewModel">
<IncludeRolloverModifier>true</IncludeRolloverModifier>
<IncludeTooltipModifier>true</IncludeTooltipModifier>
<IncludeSeriesValueModifier>true</IncludeSeriesValueModifier>
<IncludeSeriesSelectionModifier>true</IncludeSeriesSelectionModifier>
<IncludeDataPointSelectionModifier>true</IncludeDataPointSelectionModifier>
<IsDigitalLine>false</IsDigitalLine>
<Tag xmlns:q1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q1:guid">0e2411a0-7b8f-4788-b636-122a9499a62b</Tag>
<Opacity>1</Opacity>
<IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
<AntiAliasing>true</AntiAliasing>
<Stroke>
<A>255</A>
<R>0</R>
<G>128</G>
<B>0</B>
<ScA>1</ScA>
<ScR>0</ScR>
<ScG>0.21586053</ScG>
<ScB>0</ScB>
</Stroke>
<IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
<StrokeThickness>1</StrokeThickness>
<ResamplingMode>Auto</ResamplingMode>
<XAxisId>DefaultAxisId</XAxisId>
<YAxisId>DefaultAxisId</YAxisId>
<ZeroLineY>0</ZeroLineY>
<DrawNaNAs>Gaps</DrawNaNAs>
<StrokeUp xsi:nil="true"/>
<StrokeDown xsi:nil="true"/>
<DataPointWidth>0.8</DataPointWidth>
</BaseRenderableSeriesViewModel>
</ArrayOfBaseRenderableSeriesViewModel>
</BaseIndicator>
</ArrayOfBaseIndicator>
</BaseContener>
</ArrayOfBaseContener>
</ChartWindow>
</SWorkspace>
```

here is my IxmlSerialization for class causing the issue.

```
 BaseContener Serialization:

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
    writer.WriteAttributeString(nameof(ContenerGuid), this.ContenerGuid.ToString());
                  
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<BaseIndicator>));          
    serializer.Serialize(writer, actifIndicators);
    }
```

BaseContener Deserialization:

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            ContenerGuid = Guid.Parse(reader.GetAttribute(nameof(ContenerGuid)));
            OnInitialization();
            while (reader.Read())
            { 
                   switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                   
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                       
                      if (reader.Name == "BaseIndicator")
                        {

                            if (!reader.HasAttributes)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("No Attributs");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string type = reader.GetAttribute("type");
                                reader.Read(); // consume the value
                                if (type != "null")
                                {
                                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(Type.GetType(type));
                                    var indicator = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                                }
                               
                            }
                        
                        }
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
```

For the indicator deserialisation:

```
  public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            Type[] SuportedTypes = new Type[] { typeof(CandlestickRenderableSeriesViewModel), typeof(LineRenderableSeriesViewModel) };


            writer.WriteAttributeString(nameof(Name), this.GetType().Name);
            writer.WriteAttributeString(nameof(BarType), BarType.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
         

             XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<BaseRenderableSeriesViewModel>) , SuportedTypes) ;
             serializer.Serialize(writer, SeriesViewModels);
}


  

public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            //Deserialization crash before this point
            Name = reader.GetAttribute(nameof(Name));
    
            while (reader.Read())
            {  
                
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                   
                   

                }
            }
        }
```

the error is :

ArrayOfBaseRenderableSeriesViewModel was not expected

Any idea how to fix this?

as correction i will add the main probleme is my object is unknown in deserialization cuz baserenderableViewModel is from an other project i refenced.So i added reference to the namespace scichart that i don't own.

```
    XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute();            
    XmlAttributeOverrides Xoveride = new XmlAttributeOverrides();         
    root.Namespace = "http://schemas.abtsoftware.co.uk/scichart";
  
  

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(SeriesViewModels.GetType(),Xoveride, SuportedTypes ,root, "http://schemas.abtsoftware.co.uk/scichart") ;
    serializer.Serialize(writer, SeriesViewModels);
```

Comment: Xml serialization assumes for arrays that there are two tags <parent><child></child></parent>.   So either you use the attribute [XmlElement("parent")] to indicate there is one tag or you use [XmlArray("parent")] and [XmlArrayItem("child")]

Comment: my array ArrayOfBaseIndicator is working well  so is ArrayOfBaseContener i dont see why ArrayOfBaseRenderableSeriesViewModel wont work the same and is bloking.

Comment: It should be exactly like my working code below.  I do not know why you need a custom parser.

Comment: I dont own the object  RenderableSeriesViewModel its from dll and can be different type. so i need set the child name and specifie all type[] it support as serialization its why it work different my other array i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SWorkspace));
            SWorkspace sWorkspace = (SWorkspace)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    public class SWorkspace
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string NosWorkSpaceGuid { get; set; }

        public ChartWindow ChartWindow { get; set; }

    }
    public class ChartWindow
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string WindowsGuid { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Top { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Height { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Left { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Width { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("ArrayOfBaseContener")]
        [XmlArrayItem("BaseContener")]
        public List<BaseContener> BaseContener { get; set; }
    }
    public class BaseContener
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string ContenerGuid { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("ArrayOfBaseIndicator")]
        [XmlArrayItem("BaseIndicator")]
        public List<BaseIndicator> BaseIndicator { get; set; }
    }
    public class BaseIndicator
    {
        [XmlArray("ArrayOfBaseRenderableSeriesViewModel")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "BaseRenderableSeriesViewModel", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public List<BaseRenderableSeriesViewModel> BaseRenderableSeriesViewModel { get; set; }
    }
 
    [XmlInclude(typeof(CandlestickRenderableSeriesViewModel))]
    public class BaseRenderableSeriesViewModel
    {
    }
    public class CandlestickRenderableSeriesViewModel : BaseRenderableSeriesViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it give same error. is there away i build the xml array from code like creating element? like    writer.WriteStartElement("ArrayOfWhatIwant");

Comment: I found issue. You have a inherited type and need to use XmlInclude. See updated code above. The type attribute indicates an inherited class : <BaseRenderableSeriesViewModel xsi:type="CandlestickRenderableSeriesViewModel">

Comment: i think you are right but the problem is i use IXmlSerializer and the writer seem ignore this kind of tag it must have a way to do it in the void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) methode but not sure how to write it.

Comment: i understand the problem now some of serialized object come from other project so without right nameSpace object is unknown will work on it will not be easy im fall in cycling reference too ;)

Comment: I primarily use Xml Linq and Xml Serialization to parse xml.  When I need special customization I try putting it in the get/set properties of the serialization methods to avoid using IXmlSerializable.  When I have to use IXmlSerializable I convert the xmlreader into xml linq by doing following : XElement element = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);